# I have a specific json and I would like to make it a dataframe of some JSON values

Tags: python, json, list, dataframe

I have a specific json and I would like to make it a dataframe of some JSON values.

I would like one column of the dataframe to be the intensity values ​​and another column of the dataframe to be the mass values. The rest of the information contained in the JSON is not useful to me.

| intensities | masses |
| --- | --- |
| value | value |
| value | value |

the JSON file : watch pic

The url : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yZdA-eNISHwZuS2lu1gMHf5ACZyHWZrt/view?usp=sharing

I start with this :

```py
f = open('top1.json')
data = json.load(f)

values = {k: v for k, v in data.items() if k.startswith('value')}
val_list = list(valeurs.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
f = open('top1.json')
data = json.load(f)
pd.DataFrame({"intensities":data['value'][0]['intensities'],
              "masses":data['value'][0]['masses']})
```

Comment: I would add to use `with open('top1.json') as f` but yep, good answer.